# Drupal 7: HTML tags stripped for every input format, even PHP format

Tags: filter, drupal-7, drupal-input-format

I have a Drupal 7 installation, multilingual. No matter which input format i'm choosing for the node body, every HTML tag is stripped. The input format is well configured. It's like Drupal always uses Plain Text as Filter, even if Full HTML is selected.

Comment: Do you have this problem if you are creating a Node or when you are translating it?

Comment: On nodes and translations of nodes

Comment: Are there errors in js with Console (on firebug etc)? What wysiwyg editor and modules do you use (if so)? Does this happen from the installation of the site or modules or happened sometime during development?

Comment: No JS error. I'm using TinyMCE, but it does the same without wysiwyg. It has happened during development.

Comment: If you are using i18n module did you enable the "Translatable Text Formats" in admin/config/regional/i18n/strings?

Comment: Yes, I did and I refreshed the strings, but still the same. Here's the link to the website, if this helps: http://animateur.snj.lu/fr/pret-de-materiel-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the Drupal Forum:
https://drupal.org/node/1829860

> For the records: After some searching I found the culprit: I defined a
>   custom display setting for the content type article
>   (/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display) and changed (by
>   mistake) the field format to "plain text" for the body text. Reverting
>   to "default" fixed the problem.